# Debug WP7 app without zune

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

During the debugging of my WP7 app I want to access photo gallery, which is not possible if you are connected to zune, but zune is required to attach a debugger.

I know there a batch script which allows to connect a debugger to your WP7 app without zune, but I don't remember the name of that script, neither I can find it on the web. Please share a link if you know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have connected with Zune, you can close Zune and then run `WPConnect.exe`

Find it at:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x64\WPConnect.exe"

This will allow VS to connect to the device and debug your app but without the locking of parts of the OS (such as photos and the Zune library).